# How to handle onblur event with selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, onblur

I have an onblur event which I need to trigger when I click away. 
I am using js as

```
((JavascriptExecutor)getDriverProvider().executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('xpath here').onblur();");
```

but this doesn't work. Can anyone suggest how to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to use a js script (the js function is fireEvent):

```js
function fireEvent(el, type){
  if ((el[type] || false) && typeof el[type] == 'function')
  {
    el[type](el);
  }
}
$(function () {
  $('#myBtn').mouseover(function(e) {
    fireEvent(document.getElementById('myInput'), 'blur');
  });
  $('#myInput').blur(function(e) {
    alert('ok');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<input id="myInput">
<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
```